# how to get data on change of dropdown value in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to fetch data on change event of `dropdown` .Firstly I loaded `list of banks` on load or when component in loaded. Now I want to fetch `state` list when user select any `bank` .I am getting this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this3.setState is not a function
    at eval (rro780nklq.codesandbox.io/src/form_component.js:71)
    at <anonymous>
```

I tried like this

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DropDown
          data={this.state.data}
          defaultOption="select Bank"
          callbackFn={this.callStateService}
        />
        <DropDown data={this.state.stateData} defaultOption="select State" />
        <DropDown data={this.state.district} defaultOption="select District" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**onchange event**

```
onChangeDropdown = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.props.callbackFn(e.target.value);
  };
```

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/rro780nklq

Comment: Your problem isn't with this code. It's with callback function. Make sure that whatever is passed to `callbackFn` is bound to the correct object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the error related to setState using arrow function, but still there are more errors apart from this. That you need to check

```
callStateService = (bankname) => {
    axios
      .get(
        "your url"
          bankname
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.data);
        const d = response.data.data;
        this.setState({
          stateData: d
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: remove url of service pls

Comment: <<but still there are more errors apart from this>>i didn't find any error after this

Comment: ok cool no problem !!. i just saw in the console, some props error was showing up

Answer (score 0):

You can define `callStateService` as arrow function for preserving `this`:

```
callStateService = bankname => {
...
```